# GitLab: How to pull only required folders from git remote repository

Tags: git, gitlab, git-pull

I want to pull some components of my project from GitLab remote repository. Is it possible with some remote or local git setting?

Note: Can I do it as a single developer not affecting our developers of the project.

Comment: If you already have a local git clone, when you `git pull` it just pulls the `diff`. If github provides an option for you to download individual folders then you can. But git can't fo this. (You can always use wget)

Comment: What's your goal? Why do you want only some directories?

Comment: So every developer don't have to pull all project but only his compliable code component

Comment: git is a `Directed Acyclic Graph`. It builds a graph data-structure where each node is a blob of difference from the previous node. So if you need all the files that was added yesterday, you still have to clone the whole repo. You can always "download" the needed file. But then it won't be git tracked.

Comment: I don't want to /download/clone all project folders. can I do some setting locally

Comment: If you wish to use git, then you can't download just a few file (I explained why this can't be done, above). But you can download just the needed files from GitLab. Use wget or something like that

Comment: Researching on below Git features
sparse checkout
shallow clone
partial clone
These might resolve my issue

Answer (score 0):

From your topdir do

```
git fetch

git checkout HEAD path/to/folder
```

this will do it for you